# Removing files - Silent failure issue

Tags: unix, wildcard, tcsh, rm

In a Unix environment, I have a bash script that removes some files:

```
rm -f foo bar* baz*
```

My problem: not always the wildcard returns any result. And as a result of that, I fail to remove even 'foo' which always exists. The output written is "rm: No match".

A simple workaround would be to split the command:

```
rm -f foo
rm -f bar*
rm -f baz*
```

But it's a bad solution.

Comment: Not sure what environment you use. In my case (Linux/Bash/GNU-tools), it works just fine: http://depesz.privatepaste.com/d0b88c536f

Comment: Why is that bad?  Plus your first solution  works just fine on my system...  and you will get an error if bar* or baz* is not there, this is expected behavior.

Comment: My environment is SunOS. Your exact example is not working for me.


It's bad because I want all files gone. If some were not present in the first place, it shouldn't matter. I get that maybe it's expected behavior for 'rm'. Then is there some other command that could do this in a simple way?

Comment: If you just want them to no longer exist, regardless of whether they currently exist, try `rm -f foo bar* baz* 2>> /dev/null` to ignore the warning message...

Comment: I don't care about the message, only about the failure to remove even 'foo'

Comment: You say in a comment that you're using `tcsh`. If so, it's not a "bash script", it's a "tcsh script". I changed the tag but didn't change the question, in case you are really using `bash` as well.

Answer (score 1):

### zsh equivalent

```
rm: <path>: No such file or directory
```

### Fix:

```
setopt no_nomatch
```

With this successful match will be removed and an error will be logged for an unsuccessful match.

Add to `.zshrc` to enable this option to all sessions by default.

Answer (score 0):

No it should work. Which shell is used ? Is `rm` an internal version or an external ? (Try `/bin/rm` instead to ensure the external version). You may have some shell option set that prevent you to execute the command in that case (this may depend on your shell).

Comment: I'm using tcsh. And am definitely using /bin/rm. Where can I check for these shell options?

Comment: Ok I tried and I've been able to get the same message when `foo` is a directory. Is it you case ? Seems to be a problem with `tcsh` globs. Try another shell. I'm still looking at `tcsh` options...

Comment: Got it! Use `nonomatch` option. `set nonomatch` will work, it is a env variable that is used by `tcsh` to prevent expansion is case of `unmatched` regexp.

Comment: Uhh. Why did you set the bash tag on a tcsh question.  They are very different.  +1 @Jean-BaptisteYunès

Comment: Well I didn't know that it mattered.. :P Thanks Jean-Baptiste, It worked! Maybe edit your answer so I can accept it?